# return distinct records from joined tables

Tags: sql

[image]I'm trying to figure out how to return distinct records from patientcase table from the report query below:

```
select distinct rp.patientid
    p.mdpa11cd as mma, p.mdpa12cd as mmb, 
    test.mica1cd as mmc, test.mica2cd as mmdr, 
    lastnm, firstnm, hospitalid, ssnbr, 
    rp.relationshiptypecd, 
    isnull(p.ma1eqcd, '') A1s, 
    isnull(p.ma2eqcd, '') A2s, 
    isnull(p.mb1eqcd, '') B1s, 
    isnull(p.mb2eqcd, '') B2s, 
    isnull(p.mc1eqcd, '') C1s, 
    isnull(p.mc2eqcd, '') C2s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb11eqcd, '') DR1s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb12eqcd, '') DR2s, 
    isnull(p.mdqb11eqcd, '') DQ1s, 
    isnull(p.mdqb12eqcd, '') DQ2s, 
    isnull(p.mdpb11eqcd, '') DP1s, 
    isnull(p.mdpb12eqcd, '') DP2s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb31eqcd, '') DRB31s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb32eqcd, '') DRB32s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb41eqcd, '') DRB41s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb42eqcd, '') DRB42s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb51eqcd, '') DRB51s, 
    isnull(p.mdrb52eqcd, '') DRB52s, 
    p.ma1cd, p.ma2cd, p.mb1cd, p.mb2cd, p.mc1cd, p.mc2cd, 
    p.mdrb11cd, p.mdrb12cd, p.mdqb11cd, p.mdqb12cd, p.mdpb11cd, 
    p.mdpb12cd, p.mdrb31cd, p.mdrb32cd, p.mdrb41cd, p.mdrb42cd, 
    p.mdrb51cd, p.mdrb52cd, p.lastmolecularsampledt, 
    isnull(rp.mamismatchcd, '') MMa, 
    isnull(rp.mbmismatchcd, '') MMb, 
    isnull(rp.mcmismatchcd, '') MMc, 
    isnull(rp.mdrb1mismatchcd, '') MMdr,  
    isnull(rp.mdqb1mismatchcd, '') MMdq, 
    rp.mdpb1mismatchcd MMdpb1,  
    isnull(rp.mamismatchantigencd, '') Ma, 
    isnull(rp.mbmismatchantigencd, '') Mb, 
    isnull(rp.mcmismatchantigencd, '') Mc, 
    isnull(rp.mdrb1mismatchantigencd, '') Mdr,  
    isnull(rp.mdqb1mismatchantigencd, '') Mdq, 
    rp.mdpb1mismatchantigencd Mdpb1, suppressnameind, patienttypecd, 
    isnull(p.mdqa11eqcd, '') DQA1s, 
    isnull(p.mdqa12eqcd, '') DQA2s, 
    p.mdqa11cd, p.mdqa12cd, rp.mdqa1mismatchcd MMdqa1, 
    rp.mdqa1mismatchantigencd Mdqa1, p.mbw1cd, p.mbw2cd, 
    rp.haplotype1cd, rp.haplotype2cd 
from
    patientcase 
inner join 
    relatedpatient rp on rp.caseid = patientcase.caseid 
inner join 
    patient p on rp.relatedpatientid = P.patientid 
left join 
    sample on sample.patientid = p.patientid 
left join 
    test on test.sampleid = sample.sampleid
where 
    patientcase.caseid = `<Patient Cases>` 
    and rp.relatedpatientid IN `(<Donor>)` 
order by 
    rp.ordernbr asc, sample.sampledt desc
```

I've tried changing the join to left but no luck.  Please suggest how to make this work. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What do you meen didn't work, did you recieve 2 identical rows in result?

Comment: Yes, I got two identical rows in the result and one unique. I was expecting two unique rows. thanks

Comment: I've tried distinct rp.patientid but it repeated the patient twice for some reason. patient id is unique to each patient. thanks

Comment: would you please specify the tables schema. since if two tables share more than one column and you only join of one column, it could results in duplicate.

Comment: I'm adjusting a query inside an application. The database is located on 2008 SQL server. thanks

Comment: what is the relation between patient case and related patient? do they only share caseId or they share patient id as well? if latter then may be you have to add that constion to join clause as well

Comment: my suggestion is to start from first join and add the other joins incrementally to see where duplicate rows are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "distinct records from `patientcase` table" here?

Your records aren't from `patientcase` table, consider they came from a kind of anonymous, unnamed table that combines records defined by your joins & conditions  - so what would be "distinct" in this context?

If you want to do your joins **on** distinct records from `patientcase` - than it's simpler: select/join from/with subquery that narrows the source table that way, something like:

```
select 
    p.mdpa11cd as mma, p.mdpa12cd as mmb, 
    test.mica1cd as mmc, test.mica2cd as mmdr, 
    pcd.lastnm, pcd.firstnm, pcd.hospitalid, pcd.ssnbr, 
    rp.relationshiptypecd, 
    ...
from
    (SELECT DISTINCT lastnm, firstnm, hospitalid, ssnbr, caseid, ... FROM patientcase) pcd
inner join 
    relatedpatient rp on rp.caseid = pcd.caseid 
...
```

If that is not what you want - please elaborate on that, as it is way from being clear.

Comment: so, the select statement will be the same, correct? you are just adding a query after "from" and that query will contain all fields from patientcase, correct? otherwise, everything else is the same? thanks

Comment: That depends on what you exactly want to get. To me that is not yet clear, I must admit.